# Connect to Postgres via WireGuard

Tags: vpn, postgresql, wireguard

I forwarded the Postgres port for the WireGuard client:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 186.29.26.175 --dport 5432 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.50.0.4:5432
```

Please tell me is this the correct command?